# Ionic dynamic tabs, ui-router navigation not loading proper views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I built a simple application that has a home page, a login page and a contacts page, based on the [Ionic example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz). My application is [here](http://codepen.io/LymanZerga/pen/vLmvvP). Login controller sets a `$rootScope.user` variable when we log in:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $state) {
  $scope.login = function(){
    $rootScope.user = {name:"lyman"};
    $state.go("tabs.contact");
  };
})
```

After login we correctly get redirected to the Contacts screen, Contacts tab is shown and highlighted. Now click on the Home tab. Expected behavior: I should see the Home page saying I'm logged in. What I get: the title changes to Home, Home tab is highlighted, but the view changes to templates/login.html template! You can still navigate to Contacts, log out from there, and then navigation stops working altogether. What am I missing?

Another oddity is that `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives are being completely ignored when trying to hide and show tabs, only `ng-if` works. I'm thinking maybe the issue is because I'm using `ng-if` to insert and remove tabs from the markup and with `ion-nav-view` residing inside of the `ion-tab` tab? What would be the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, using `ng-if` to hide/show tabs will screw up navigation. The solution is to use the tab's `hidden` property as demonstrated in this [fork of my original example](http://codepen.io/LymanZerga/pen/gPWqjw):

```
<ion-tab title="Log In" icon="ion-ios-person" ui-sref="tabs.login" hidden="{{ loggedIn() }}">
        <ion-nav-view name="login-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('TabsCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.loggedIn = function() {
      if ($rootScope.user) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };
  })
```